# Let Linearlayout width be 650dp if parent is over 650dp, otherwise match parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating a LinearLayout inside a FrameLayout, the LinearLayout needs to be centered inside FrameLayout, but the width of LinearLayout needs to change as follows:
If parent FrameLayout is over 650dp, then set LinearLayout width to 650dp, this leaves some margin at left and right of linear layout.

If parent FrameLayout is under 650dp, then set Lineralyout width to match parent.

Parent FrameLayout width will change on orientation change, I tried to use OnLayoutChangeListener, OnGlobalLayoutListener, OnAttachStateChangeListenerto detect the width after screen rotates, but none of them works.

Am I on the right track by trying to find the width of parent view?

Or is it possible to use parent view as ConstraintLayout and make the LinearLayout inside comply 650 when possible and expand to parent when width is not enough?

(Note I can't use different values under different layout res folders like sw600 or sw600-land, as the parentview is not necessarily occupying the entire screen, it might just be one of the two columns on the screen)

Comment: Children of `ConstraintLayout` (not `CoordinatorLayout`) can specify `app:layout_constraintWidth_max`.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate way to handle this is to create another layout file under `layout-land` and use a 650dp width for that. And for more description on supporting different screens [see the official training here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html).

Comment: The issue is that I can't assume screen width equal to parentView width, for example the Parent frameLayout might be in one of the two columns on tablet landscape. In this case even though screenwidth is sw720, I might still need to make it match parent.

Comment: Still, you can apply the same logic I mentioned on the width qualifier. Meaning you would create a new `styles.xml` and give it a 650dp width qualifier and in there you would define the width of your linear layout.
You should definitely see how to create different styles for different widths in the same link above.

Comment: If I define a style with 650 in sw720 and have a two column view on a 720 width screen, the column might just be 300dp wide, in which case setting 650 would make the view wider than screen

Answer (score 0):

For any one interested, I solved it with a ConstraintLayout per Eugen's comment. This will make sure the LinearLayout's width matches parent on smaller screens(<650dp) and cap the width to 650dp on bigger screen sizes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/row_content"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintWidth_max="650dp"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#f00"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:background="#00f"
        >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Result when parent width = 150dp

[image]